# Qt6 QML Font glow effect

Tags: qml, qt6

How to use QT6 QML to achieve font lighting effect. I know use Golw in import qt5compat graphicaleffects. However, after the golw is deleted by QT6 QML, does it not have its own function to realize font lighting?

Comment: You can use [Qt 5 Compatibility API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html)

Comment: You use python or c++?